# Why does the map download not work on Shiny IO?

Tags: r, shiny, download, shinyapps, r-leaflet

I have an issue with providing a download option in my Shiny application. The download button works fine locally. Once the application is exported to Shiny IO the download does not work anymore. On Firefox a new empty tab opens and on Google Chrome the message in downloads is "error - unknown server error".

A similar question has been asked before, but was not answered or seems outdated:

- [Downloading wordcloud2 output as png/jpg on shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54260164/downloading-wordcloud2-output-as-png-jpg-on-shiny/54287988#54287988)
- [Download leaflet map as a png when shiny app is deployed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59519438/download-leaflet-map-as-a-png-when-shiny-app-is-deployed)

I condensed my code to the most basic version.

```
# Load the necessary packages
library("shiny")
library("leaflet")
library("mapview")

### UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  leafletOutput(outputId = "map"),
  downloadButton(outputId = "dl")
  
)

### Sever
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Create foundational leaflet map
  # and store it as a reactive expression
  foundational.map <- reactive({
    
    leaflet()  %>%
    setView(13.39883565902603, 52.532396478732, zoom = 11) %>%
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron", 
                       group="Greyscale")
  }) # end of foundational.map()
  
  # render foundational leaflet map
  output$map <- leaflet::renderLeaflet({
    
    # call reactive map
    foundational.map()
    
  }) # end of render leaflet
  
  # Store the current user-created version
  # of the Leaflet map for download in 
  # a reactive expression
  user.created.map <- reactive({
    
    # call the foundational Leaflet map
    foundational.map() %>%
      
      # store the view based on UI
      setView( lng = input$map_center$lng
               ,  lat = input$map_center$lat
               , zoom = input$map_zoom
      )
    
  }) # end of creating user.created.map()
  
  
  
  # Output of the map
  output$dl <- downloadHandler(
    
     filename = paste0( Sys.Date()
                        , "_customLeafletmap"
                        , ".png"
     )
     
     , content = function(file) {
       mapshot( x = user.created.map()
                , file = file
                , cliprect = "viewport" # the clipping rectangle matches the height & width from the viewing port
       )
     } # end of content() function
   ) # end of downloadHandler() function
  
} # end of server

### Run the Shiny app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```